# How to Search parent content from multiple table?

Tags: mysql

Table - parents

```
+----+----------+--------------+----------+
| id | user_id  | content_type |  name    |
+----+----------+--------------+----------+
|  1 | 10       | 1            | name - 1 |
|  2 | 12       | 2            | name - 2 |
+----+----------+--------------+----------+
```

`content_type` can be

```
1 = Single part(movies)
2 = Multi prt(serials, episode)
```

Table - childs

```
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| id | parent_id  | is_episode   | episode_name | file_name |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | 1          | 0            | NULL         | movie.mp4 |
|  2 | 2          | 0            | NULL         | zee.mp4   |
|  3 | 2          | 1            | cname-2      | lil-1.mp4 |
|  4 | 2          | 1            | child-2      | lil-2.mp4 |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

And `is_episode` can be:

```
0 = No
1 = Yes
```

NB: some other fields I have skipped

My QUERY:

```
SELECT F.id,F.user_id,F.content_type,F.name,M.is_episode, M.episode_name, M.file_name 
FROM childs M,parents F 
WHERE  M.parent_id = F.id AND M.is_episode=0 AND 
(F.name LIKE '%child%' OR M.episode_name LIKE '%child%' )
```

Abve MySQL query I am getting 0 record. There is 1 content

My search string applied based on `parents.name` or `childs.episode_name` I want to get all record which are `is_episode=0` If I search `child-2` then findout parent content of my current record. Here is my output should come

```
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| id | user_id  | content_type   | name     | is_episode | episode_name | file_name |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  2 | 12       | 2              | name - 2 | 0          | NULL         | zee.mp4   |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

OUTPUTS:

```
In above my  two tables my output should come following criterias
```

If I search by `name LIKE '%name%'` output should be

```
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| id | user_id  | content_type   | name     | is_episode | episode_name |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | 10       | 1              | name - 1 | 0          | NULL         |
|  2 | 12       | 2              | name - 2 | 0          | NULL         |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

If I search by `name LIKE '%cname%'` or `name LIKE '%name - 2%'` or `name LIKE '%child%'` output should be

```
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| id | user_id  | content_type   | name     | is_episode | episode_name |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
|  2 | 12       | 2              | name - 2 | 0          | NULL         |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

If I search by `name LIKE '%name - 1%'` output should be

```
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| id | user_id  | content_type   | name     | is_episode | episode_name |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | 10       | 1              | name - 1 | 0          | NULL         |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

If I search by `name LIKE '%child%'` output should be

```
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| id | user_id  | content_type   | name     | is_episode | episode_name |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
|  2 | 12       | 2              | name - 2 | 0          | NULL         |
+----+----------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

I am unable to get proper output of my query. Could you plese write down query which is satisfied my all the output.

Comment: I don't if I understood what you need exactly, do you need to get results if they are in parent or child, right

Comment: if so you should join both tables, I added coalesce for NULL, trim and lcase too, if it is working let me know to post as an answer ----  FROM childs M inner join parents F 
    on  M.parent_id = F.id AND M.is_episode=0 
    where 
    (lcase(trim(COALESCE(F.name,''))) LIKE '%child%' OR lcase(trim(COALESCE(M.episode_name,''))) LIKE '%child%' )

Comment: @msoliman I need all the parent record. If i search any child text from `episode_name` parent record should come

Comment: @msoliman see my last output of my question. I have searched `child` but parent content will come which child record `episode_name` are `child`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're filtering out **only** rows that has `Is_episode = 0` however you need to search in the rows that has `is_episode = 1` like `cname-2` and `child-2`

your problem caused because `is_episode = 0`, remove it and it should work.  please leave a comment if you still have a problem.

**Update**: based in your comments, based on my understanding I think you may require some sort of multiple `queries` and separation based on the `table` or your `logic/conditions` then `union` results together.

```
select .. from parent, child .. where is_episode = 0 and name like ... 
union 
select .. from child join parent where episode_name like ...
```

Comment: If I remove `is_episode=0` then my child row will come. I  want to show all parent records as per my search string.